# Is there a way of reducing the quantity nested if/elif statements for this problem?

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement, conditional-statements

I am trying to find the maximum of two numbers(totMax and totMin), each number a corresponding lists of unknown values (totMax to maxList and totMin to minList) which are the same length. I need to store the list which corresponds to the largest of both numbers in the variable 'highest', assuming both numbers are both bellow 20. If only one of the numbers meets the condition, then the corresponding list to that number will be stored. The number stored in totMax with always be higher that the number store in totMin. Is there a more concise way of doing this?

```
if totMax > 20 and totMin > 20: 
      raise ValueError(f"Both out of range")
    elif totMax <= 20:
      highest = maxList
    elif totMin <= 20:
      highest = minList
    return highest
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The other answerers seem to have missed your requirement to return not the value you are testing, but an associated list.  I played with this a little and came up with:

```
if totMax <= 20:
    highest = maxList
elif totMin > 20: 
    raise ValueError(f"Both out of range")
else :
    highest = minList
return highest
```

Which can be further tweaked to:

```
if totMax <= 20:
    return maxList
if totMin > 20: 
    raise ValueError(f"Both out of range")
else :
    return minList
```

But, looking at it from a maintenance point of view, your organization is more clear and expresses the requirements more closely to the English language understanding of the requirement specification.

The only change I would recommend making to your code is that the last `elif` could be a simple `else`.

Answer (score 3):

Why not use a `max()` command:

```
if totMax > 20 and totMin > 20:
    raise ValueError(f"Both out of range")
else:
    highest=max(totMax,totMin)
    return highest
```

**OR**

Because:

> The number stored in totMax with always be higher that the number store in totMin.

```
if totMax > 20 and totMin > 20:
    raise ValueError(f"Both out of range")
else:
    highest=totMax
    return highest
```

Answer (score 3):

Since you want to return one value that's associated with another, I'd start by making a dict to express that association, and then do the selection using `max` and a filter:

```
total_lists = {
    totMin: minList,
    totMax: maxList,
}
return total_lists[max(t for t in total_lists.keys() if t <= 20)]
```

If `totMin` and `totMax` are the totals of the values in the respective lists, I'd not use those variables at all and just use `sum` to make it simpler:

```
return max((v for v in (minList, maxList) if sum(v) <= 20), key=sum)
```

(edit) aha, like others I totally missed that there was another set of values here.  Going to leave original answer below for posterity but edit in the way I'd handle this with the associated lists.  See below for notes on exception handling.

---

In the general case I might do this type of thing by building a list of "candidate" values (i.e. those that are within the desired range) and then returning the `max` of them.  It might seem a little overkill for only two values, but I tend to think that any time you have more than one value you should be putting them in a collection.  Once your values are in a filtered list, it's easy to reason about them in terms of "is this list empty" and "what's the highest element of this list" without having to write individual `if`/`elif` checks on each element:

```
values = [v for v in (totMax, totMin) if v <= 20]
if not values:
    raise ValueError("Both out of range")
return max(values)
```

Since in your case you can assume that `totMax` is always higher than `totMin`, you can assume that `values` is sorted, and so you'd have the option of just returning the first element instead of using `max`.  (This is a *little* tricky since it may not be obvious to a future editor of the code that you're depending on the ordering of the input list!)

```
values = [v for v in (totMax, totMin) if v <= 20]
if not values:
    raise ValueError("Both out of range")
return values[0]  # this works because the original values were in descending order
```

Note that if you aren't picky about providing custom text for the exception, you can do this as a one-liner:

```
# raises ValueError: 'max() arg is an empty sequence' if both values > 20
return max(v for v in (totMax, totMin) if v <= 20)
```

or you could rewrite the exception in a `try`/`except` rather than using an `if`:

```
try:
    return [v for v in (totMax, totMin) if v <= 20][0]
except IndexError:
    raise ValueError("Both out of range")
```

Ultimately, which of these options you pick comes down to your requirements for the interface and what your stylistic preferences are!  (I'd personally go for the one-liner with `max`.)

Comment: Nice.  I thought about using a `dict`, but did not see a quick way to avoid making it more complicated/complex.  I need to practice comprehensions more.